# Calculate dispatch day for shipment

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

SQL Server

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DispatchTime]
(
     [dis_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
     [dis_fk_pro] [int] NOT NULL,
     [dis_weekDay] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
     [dis_displayDay] [varchar](12) NULL,
     [dis_time] [time](0) NOT NULL,

     CONSTRAINT [PK_DispatchTime] PRIMARY KEY (dis_ID)
)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o688Q.png

I have a table that contains information about dispatch time for weekdays.
The input to the query is datetime like '2015-01-27 13:30:00'

The idea is that from the date time I should determine which day the dispatch will happen. The logic is that from the date if it is e.g. a Tuesday as in this example and the time is less or equal to the time in dis_time then this is day for dispatch. If the time is greater I need to check for the next day that fits the dispatch time criteria and then add the day to the input date as output.
The dis_times that is 00:00:00 indicates that no time is set for that day and that day is not a day for dispatch. I could change that to NULL but for now it is like so.

I have tried a lot of things and it get worse every time I try.

I know I can find and match the input day and time and do a lot of if tests based on that, but I have not succeeded to get the result I describe.

```sql
DECLARE @fromTime AS datetime
SET DATEFIRST 1
SET @fromTime = '2015-01-27 13:30:00

SELECT *
FROM DispatchTime
WHERE dis_weekDay = DATEPART(dw,@fromTime)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fosr.png

So what I need is a way to find the next day for dispatch, it could also be like it would be in the next week if e.g. in e.g. the date / day is a Sunday and the next day is then Tuesday the following week that fulfill the dispatch time criteria.

I have tried with a CTE with LAG and LEAD but is it not worth posting as it is totally off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#DispatchTime') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #DispatchTime
CREATE TABLE #DispatchTime
    (
      [dis_ID] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) ,
      [dis_fk_pro] INT ,
      [dis_weekDay] TINYINT ,
      [dis_displayDay] VARCHAR(12) ,
      [dis_time] TIME(0)
    )

INSERT  INTO #DispatchTime
        ( dis_fk_pro, dis_weekDay, dis_displayDay, dis_time )
VALUES  ( 1, 1, 'Monday', '00:00:00' ),
        ( 1, 2, 'Tuesday', '13:30:00' ),
        ( 1, 3, 'Wednesday', '12:30:00' ),
        ( 1, 4, 'Thursday', '12:30:00' ),
        ( 1, 5, 'Friday', '12:30:00' ),
        ( 1, 6, 'Saturday', '00:00:00' ),
        ( 1, 7, 'Sunday', '00:00:00' )


DECLARE @fromTime AS DATETIME
SET @fromTime = '2015-01-27 12:30:00'

SELECT TOP 1
        DT.dis_ID ,
        DT.dis_fk_pro ,
        DT.dis_weekDay ,
        DT.dis_displayDay ,
        DT.dis_time ,
        CASE WHEN DT.dis_weekDay >= DATEPART(dw, @fromTime)
             THEN DATEADD(d, DT.dis_weekDay - DATEPART(dw, @fromTime),
                          CONVERT(DATE, @fromTime))
             ELSE DATEADD(d, DT.dis_weekDay - DATEPART(dw, @fromTime) + 7,
                          CONVERT(DATE, @fromTime))
        END AS [Possible Dispatch Date]
FROM    #DispatchTime AS DT
WHERE   CONVERT(TIME, @fromTime) <= DT.dis_time
ORDER BY [Possible Dispatch Date]
```

Comment: Thanks a million it worked like a charm!

I just added SET DATEFIRST 1 as monday is the day first day of the week I use :)